# Is there a way to generate random passwords in Safari, without iCloud?

Tags: macos, safari, software-recommendation, password, keychain

I know that iCloud Keychain has a feature where it offers to generate strong, random passwords directly in Safari. Some third-party password managers allow it, but I'd prefer to store the password in the OS X keychain, so I'm really just looking for a password generator, not full-blown manager. For other browsers there is addons that offer similar functionality. It's possible to do it in the regular non-iCloud Keychain Access app, but this is a bit cumbersome.

Is there any way of generating a random password directly in Safari, but without using iCloud keychain?

Answer (score 13):

No there is no way in Safari directly,

You can only go directly to the Keychain  
(Spotlight -> Keychain // or via the Finder -> /Applications/Utilities/Keychain.app)

and create a new Key (CMD+N).

You will get the window with the little key icon and when you click on it, it will show you a little popup with the Password Assistant.

Comment: Yes, this I'm aware of, but as I said it is a bit cumbersome. Is there no plugin / add-on / extension that does this in Safari itself? Or maybe is there any way of tricking Safari into thinking it is using iCloud keychain?

Answer (score 3):

One can always keep a sign-up form with a displayable password field close at hand, for instance Google's. Save the link to Bookmarks > Favorites. Then when it's time:

1. Visit the site
2. Use Safari to suggest a password
3. Toggle password visibility
4. Copy the text

Comment: How do you do #3? I've often wondered if it was possible to copy the generated passwords but didn't find a way to enable it. You can only see about half the password in the form and are unable to copy it.

Answer (score 1):

When using the process proposed by @Felicio, I have also noticed that you cannot see (or copy) the entire generated password. The following steps will let you see all of it, but you still can't copy it until after it gets saved in the keychain.

1. Visit the site's registration form
2. Click in the Password box to get Safari to suggest a password
3. Click "Don't Use"
4. Click the key icon in the Password box
5. The popup shows the entire generated password following "Fill Password Again:" along with letting you pick a new one
6. At this point, I usually save a screenshot to my desktop to temporarily save the generated password just in (the rare) case that Safari doesn't successfully save the password to the keychain.